# How to draw a curve that goes both up and down?

Tags: c#-4.0, drawing

I've used the following code to make 3 points, draw them to a bitmap, then draw the bitmap to the main form, however it seems to always draw point 3 before point 2, because the Y co-ordinate is lower then point 2's. Is there a way to get over this, as I need a curve that curves up and down, rather than just up

```
            Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(490, 490);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bit);
            Graphics form = this.CreateGraphics();
            pntPoints[0] = this.pictureBox1.Location;

            pntPoints[1] = new Point(100,300);
            pntPoints[2] = new Point(200, 150);
            g.DrawCurve(p, pntPoints);


            form.DrawImage(bit, 0, 5);

            bit.Dispose();
            g.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y-coordinate for point 3 is not lower, it's actually higher. The (0;0) point of `Graphics` is in the left top corner, and the Y value increases from the top down rather than from the bottom up. So a point (0;100) will be higher than (0;200) on the result image.

If you want a curve that goes up then down, you should place your first point in (0; 489), your second point in (100, 190) and your third point in (200, 340).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you put in a debug function that will mark and identify the points themselves, so you can see exactly where they are. A pixel in an off color, the index of the point, and the coordinates together will help you identify what is going where.

Now, I'm wondering, are those two points really supposed to be absolute, or are they supposed to be relative to the first point?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've found out my error, all points are drawn from the top left of the form, rather then the bottom left, so I've been basing everything incorrectly :|